# Can't extend traces with setting the marker type

Tags: javascript, plotly, marker, extend, area

With the code below I am trying to create a simple bubble chart. I create a trace to extend it later:

```js
    var t9 = {
        x: [100821],
        y: [11],
        name: 'Some text',
        text: ['Some text'],
        mode: ['markers'],
        marker: [{
          size: [1531*10],
          sizeref: 2,
          sizemode: 'area'
        }]
      };
    var data = [t9];


var layout = {
  title: 'Chart',
  showlegend: true,
  xaxis: {
    title: 'Some text'
  },
  yaxis: {
    title: 'Some text'
  }
};

var config = {responsive: true}

Plotly.newPlot('plot', data, layout, config);



        Plotly.extendTraces(
          'plot', 
        {
          x: [[5491]],
          y: [[5]],
          text: [['Some text']],
          mode: [['markers']],
          marker: [[{
            size: 123*100,
            sizeref: 2,
            sizemode: 'area'
          }]]
        }, [0]);

        

        Plotly.extendTraces(
          'plot', 
        {
          x: [[60022]],
          y: [[11]],
          text: [['Some text']],
          mode: [['markers']],
          marker: [[{
            size: 982*100,
            sizeref: 2,
            sizemode: 'area'
          }]]
        }, [0]);
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Plotly.js -->
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="plot"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The result is this:
[image: Result]

As you can see the markers don't take on the property `mode: ['markers']` and all of the `markers:` properties.

Any idea how to get a result like on this page?
https://plotly.com/javascript/bubble-charts/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you use `extendTraces` and want to update properties, such marker size you need to provide the attribute as a string, e.g. `marker.size` and the value must be an array, just like your new x and y values.

  ```
  Plotly.extendTraces(
    'plot', 
    {
      x: [[5491]],
      y: [[5]],
      'marker.size':[[40*100]]
    }, [0]);
  ```
- Your initial data and attributes should be a simple array or object, not an array of arrays/objects.
  [image]

  ```js
   var t9 = {
    x: [100821],
    y: [11],
    name: 'Some text',
    text: 'Some text',
    mode: 'markers',
    marker: {
      size: [15*100],
      sizeref: 1,
      sizemode: 'area'
    }
  };

  var data = [t9];

  var layout = {
    title: 'Chart',
    showlegend: true,
    xaxis: {
      title: 'Some text'
    },
    yaxis: {
      title: 'Some text',
      range: [-12, 30]
    }
  };

  var config = {responsive: true}

  Plotly.newPlot('plot', data, layout, config);


  Plotly.extendTraces(
    'plot', 
    {
      x: [[5491]],
      y: [[5]],
      'marker.size':[[40*100]]
    }, [0]);

  Plotly.extendTraces(
    'plot', 
    {
      x: [[60022]],
      y: [[11]],
     'marker.size':[[200*100]] 
    }, [0]);
  ```

  ```html
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <div id='plot'>

  </div>
  ```